# PySpark count groupby with None keys

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have a spark RDD object (using pyspark) and I'm trying to get the equivalent of SQL's

```
SELECT MY_FIELD COUNT(*) GROUP BY MY_FIELD
```

So I've tried the following code:

```
my_groupby_count = myRDD.map(lambda x: x.type).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y).collect()
# 'type' is the name of the field inside the RDD row
```

But I'm getting an error instead, which I'm not sure how to handle:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-23b4c60c6fd6> in <module>()
----> 1 my_groupby_count = myRDD.map(lambda x: x.type).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x +     y).collect()

/root/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py in collect(self)
         
         with SCCallSiteSync(self.context) as css:
-->              port = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
         return list(_load_from_socket(port, self._jrdd_deserializer))
 
/root/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
         return_value = get_return_value(
->              answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
```

Now, since this method has worked well for me before, I'm suspecting it might have to do with something related to the data itself. For instance, I know some values in x.type are None, but I'm not sure how to get rid of them.

Any ideas how to proceed investigating this?
P.S.
toDF() fails as well, I imagine due to whatever same reason.
Also, I'd solutions for RDD and not DataFrame.
Thanks

Comment: No. It's the same question posted by me. Due to a communication problem it was posted twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to provide tuple reduceByKey. Looks like you just forgot '()'

```
myRDD.map(lambda x: (x.type, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y).collect()
```

Side note: shorter version of the same code with countByKey()

```
myRDD.map(lambda x: (x.type,)).countByKey()
```

Comment: Thanks that's a better way do it. In any case, for future reference, the code didn't have any problem. Restarting the environment solved everything